# Calculating proportional diversity in groups

Tags: spss

In my data set, consistent of employees nested in teams, I have to calculate proportional diversity index for gender. This index is the percentage of minority group members present within each team. in my data set male coded as 0 and female as 1. Now I wonder if there is any simple way for coming up with the number of minority in each team.
Tnx for your guidance

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is just the percentage of males and females in each team you can calculate:

```
sort cases by teamVar.
split file by teamVar.
freq genderVar.
split file off.
```

This will get you the results in the output window.
If you want the results in another dataset you can use `aggregate`:

```
dataset declare byteam.
aggregate out=byteam /break=teamVar 
   /Pfemales=Pin(genderVar 1 1)
   /Pmales=Pin(genderVar 0 0).
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have to clarify that I need the percentage of minority in each team. In one team it might be female and in other male.

Comment: In general you will get more help in this site (and more helpful answers) if you give a better description of your data and what you are trying to do with it (e.g "I need to create a table that has the percentage of males and females in each group"). In any case see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Now I wonder if there is any way to ask spss  give us just the minimum amount between Pfemales and Pmales as the outcome.